# Firebase Real time database not working in india?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Until 3 of September everything was fine then this happened no values are retrieving for the user who has Vodafone and jio service providers. when i checked the firebase status dashbaord they said they have fixed it and it hapening only for small amount of people. @firebase please look into it .

Comment: Facing the same issue. did you got any response from them?

Comment: *firebaser here* if you're still seeing the issue, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so they can track. I'd also recommend reaching out to the affected providers directly, if you have a way to do so.